# Delete deployment/replication controllers openshift cli

Tags: openshift, kubernetes

Is there a way to delete previous deployments with cli?

When I successfully run `oc import-image $APPLICATION` a new deployment appears with a RC and after a few runs I hit the RC max and will have to manually delete the previous deployments.

Is there a script similar to `oc delete rc $APPLICATION-$(($DEPLOYMENT_NUMBER - 1))`?

Answer (score 4):

Over time you can end up with alot of replication controllers, and thus you need to clean them out. You can use `oc delete rc <rc-num>` or even better `oc adm prune` to do this. Checkout `oc adm options` and `oc adm prune --help` for options.

`$ oc adm prune deployments --keep-complete=5 --namespace=myproject --confirm`

Comment: The best of the above options, --keep-complete option lets you decide how many deployments to keep without pruning,

Command:
oc adm prune deployments --keep-complete=5 --namespace={{ PROJECT_NAME }} --confirm

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code to create a (rushed) solution.

```
# DEPLOYMENT_COUNT will be the number of deployments
DEPLOYMENT_COUNT=`oc get rc | wc -l` 
DEPLOYMENT_COUNT=$((DEPLOYMENT_COUNT - 1))
for ((i=1; i<$DEPLOYMENT_COUNT + 1; i++))
 do
    #CURR_POD_LINE=`oc get rc | tail -$i | head -n1`
    DEPLOYMENT_ID=`oc get rc | tail -$i | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'`
    DESIRED_PODS_COUNT=`oc get rc | tail -$i | head -n1 | awk '{print $5}'`

    # IF number of desired pods is 0, then delete the deployment
    if [ $DESIRED_PODS_COUNT -eq 0 ]
      then
        #DELETE
        oc delete rc $DEPLOYMENT_ID
    fi
    echo $DEPLOYMENT_ID
    echo $DESIRED_PODS_COUNT
 done
```